# BULK COLLECT procedure long running

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I'm having problem using bulk collect, my table contain only 10000 records can you help me find what I did wrong with my procedure.

```
DECLARE
   ctr        NUMBER;
   str        CLOB;

   CURSOR s_cur
   IS
      SELECT                                                /* +parallel(8) */
            * FROM tmp_billinfo;

   CURSOR s_cur2 (var1 VARCHAR2)
   IS
      SELECT                                                /* +parallel(8) */
            TO_CHAR (poid_id0) poid_id0, poid_type, poid_rev
        FROM pin.item_t i
       WHERE     billinfo_obj_id0 = var1
             AND status = 1;

   TYPE fetch_array IS TABLE OF s_cur%ROWTYPE;

   TYPE fetch_array2 IS TABLE OF s_cur2%ROWTYPE;

   s_array    fetch_array;
   s_array2   fetch_array2;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table tmp_hotbill_flist';

   OPEN s_cur;

   LOOP
      FETCH s_cur BULK COLLECT INTO s_array LIMIT 100;

      FOR i IN 1 .. s_array.COUNT
      LOOP
         str := NULL;
         str := 'r << e 1';
         str :=
               str
            || CHR (10)
            || '0 PIN_FLD_POID           POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /account '
            || TO_CHAR (s_array (i).account_obj_id0);
         ctr := 0;

         BEGIN
            OPEN s_cur2 (s_array (i).poid_id0);

            LOOP
               FETCH s_cur2 BULK COLLECT INTO s_array2;

               FOR i IN 1 .. s_array2.COUNT
               LOOP
                  str :=
                        str
                     || CHR (10)
                     || '0 PIN_FLD_ITEMS         ARRAY ['
                     || TO_CHAR (ctr)
                     || '] allocated 20, used 1';
                  str :=
                        str
                     || CHR (10)
                     || '1     PIN_FLD_ITEM_OBJ       POID [0] 0.0.0.1 '
                     || TO_CHAR (s_array2 (i).poid_type)
                     || ' '
                     || TO_CHAR (s_array2 (i).poid_id0)
                     || ' '
                     || TO_CHAR (s_array2 (i).poid_rev)
                     || '';
                  ctr := ctr + 1;
               END LOOP;

               EXIT WHEN s_cur2%NOTFOUND;
            END LOOP;

            CLOSE s_cur2;
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
               RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, s_array (i).bill_info_id);
         END;

         str :=
               str
            || CHR (10)
            || '0 PIN_FLD_PROGRAM_NAME    STR [0] "Testnap HOTBILL [Proj. LionHeart]"';
         str := str || CHR (10) || 'e';
         str := str || CHR (10) || 'xop PCM_OP_BILL_MAKE_BILL_NOW 0 1';

         INSERT INTO tmp_hotbill_flist
                 VALUES (
                           s_array (i).bill_info_id,
                           str,
                           'HOTBILL_' || s_array (i).bill_info_id || '.nap');
      END LOOP;

      EXIT WHEN s_cur%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE s_cur;

   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I've tried hundreds of records and it went okay, but having 10 thousand plus records makes the procedure run so long.

thanks,
Nelzki

Comment: Well, you have 4 nested loops. No wonder it takes time to complete. What to do? See if you can rewrite it.

Comment: Profiling will confirm which sections are taking the time, but I suspect it will be the inner cursor. I'd look at coding the join in SQL to give the optimiser some more options.

Comment: I also doubt parallel will help here, but the hints are incorrectly written so they aren't doing anything at the moment anyway. It's `/*+ hint */`, not `/* +hint *.`.

Comment: If you have a co-operative DBA then ask them to install DBMS_PROFILER for you. (For some reason it's not installed by default). This package will allow you to see which procedure lines are executing, how often they execute and how long they take. Armed with this information you can see where your program is spending too much time, and that's where you need to focus your tuning efforts. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_profil.htm#ARPLS039)